# How to disable schema validation in nxml-mode but keep validation of well-formedness?

Tags: nxml, xml-schema

By default, nxml-mode looks at the name of the root element and decides to validate the document against some schema based on that name.

I would like to disable this and just validate that the document is well-formed, since I edit documents in my own custom format with element names that coincides with some schema nxml-mode knows about but that is not relevant to my purposes.

I know I can toggle validation using `C-c` `C-v`, but I'd prefer to keep the check for well-formedness enabled at all times, if possible.

Comment: Does `rng-set-vacuous-schema` and using the argument `no-change-schema` to the mode function work ?

Comment: @politza: Adding `rng-set-vacuous-schema` to my nxml-mode hook did the trick! Move your comment into an answer and I'll upvote and accept it. Thanks!